# SonarScanner .NET (Framework) | Post-processing failed

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarscanner

### The situation

Hello everyone, I have a **web site project** I need to scan with the **SonarScanner .NET** because the "default cli" SonarScanner doesn't include **C#**.

### The problem

I am **not been able to pass the post-processing phase**.
`begin` and `rebuild` commands complete, but the `end` one doesn't.

*(The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.)*
*(Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete the analysis.)*

### My versions

- Windows 10
- .NET Framework 4.8
- SonarQube Community Edition 9.5 (build 56709)
- MsBuild 17.2.1 per .NET Framework
- SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.7.2

### What I have tried

I already know to run all 3 commands on the same folder. I tried both in the project folder and in the solution folder. I tried with the solution in the project folder and without.

---

##### Logs and .sonarqube folder

[File in .7z | Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zgnn4XJtBC8JUfHtj2koY6kP9DkwdZbP/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the project uses aspnet to compile, which is not supported by roslyn analyzers.

Thanks to the SonarSource community for helping me individuate the problem.

---

[SonarSource community topic in question](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarscanner-net-framework-post-processing-failed/68821)